# Textbox showing NaN, and issue with basic calculation

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, nan

I cant figure out why after I hit "compute payment" it displays `NaN`. The only reasons why I think this may be happening is because of the `computeMonthlyPayment()` function, more specifically with the calculation line. I also think it may be related to the radio buttons.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <title> Monthly Payment Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <script>
 function computeMonthlyPmt(){
  var amt = document.MonthlyPmt.LoanAmt.value;
  var r = document.MonthlyPmt.Rate.value;
  var t = document.MonthlyPmt.Year.value;
  document.MonthlyPmt.Payment.value = (amt*(r/12))/(1-Math.pow(1+(r/12),-12*t));
  
 }
    </script>

    <body>
    <h1> Monthly Payment Calculator </h1>

    <form name="MonthlyPmt">
 <p> Enter Loan:<input type="text" name="LoanAmt" value="" /> </p>
 
  
 <p> Select Rate: </p>
 <select name="Rate">
  <option value=0.04>4%</option>
  <option value=0.045>4.5%</option>
  <option value=0.05>5%</option>
  <option value=0.055>5.5%</option>
  <option value=0.06>6%</option>
 </select>

 <p> Select Term: </p> 
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value=10/>10 Years<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value=15/>15 Years<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value=30/>30 Years<br>

 <p> Monthly Payment: </p>
  <input type="text" name="Payment" value="" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Compute Payment" name="btnCompute" onclick="computeMonthlyPmt()" />

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around your attributes! Yes they can be optional, but it bit you in the rear here.

The value of year is `"30/"` not `30`.

Debug it with:

```
console.log(amt, r, t)
```

```js
function computeMonthlyPmt() {
  var amt = document.MonthlyPmt.LoanAmt.value;
  var r = document.MonthlyPmt.Rate.value;
  var t = document.MonthlyPmt.Year.value;
  document.MonthlyPmt.Payment.value = (amt * (r / 12)) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (r / 12), -12 * t));

}
```

```html
<form name="MonthlyPmt">
  <p> Enter Loan:<input type="text" name="LoanAmt" value="" /> </p>


  <p> Select Rate: </p>
  <select name="Rate">
    <option value="0.04">4%</option>
    <option value="0.045">4.5%</option>
    <option value="0.05">5%</option>
    <option value="0.055">5.5%</option>
    <option value="0.06">6%</option>
</select>

  <p> Select Term: </p>
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value="10" />10 Years<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value="15" />15 Years<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Year" value="30" />30 Years<br>

  <p> Monthly Payment: </p>
  <input type="text" name="Payment" value="" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Compute Payment" name="btnCompute" onclick="computeMonthlyPmt()" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even after changing that, I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: So you wrapped all the values in quotes?

Comment: I also noticed my </head> tag was before the <script> tag, so I moved that to after the </script> tag

Comment: I just tested it and works fine. What are you entering into the first textbox?

Comment: The values, are $300,000, 4% and 30 years

Comment: because that is not a valid number. JavaScript does not support $ and , in numbers. You would need to remove the $ and ,... test it with `300000`

Comment: I tried removing those, still not working; I also changed the value to 1000 and it keeps saying NaN

Comment: In runs in my example above with it fixed. So are you cached with old code. Hard refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just switched browsers and computers and it worked.